# Dividing long content to subpages

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I need to divide long content to sub-pages.

Rule for dividing: Heading1 (H1)

Cms-system: MODX Evolution

As far as i know, there is nothing in modx to use for this kind of problem.

I probably got to do this manually anyway, but i still would like to know if there is a way to do this in MODX Evo / Revo.

Edit:
I need to do this in MODX; sub-pages got to be actual subpages, and original page becomes to container.

Navigation will be done with wayfinder.

Edit2:
**All done.. manually. Question still open, though.**

Comment: Now I'm a bit interested, how you did it. Maybe you'd like to share your code somewhere? Might be helpful for others, too.

Comment: Like the Edit2 says my friend :) ..new resource, copy/paste content. Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box and I don't know of any extra that archieves what you want. You would have to write a plugin that acts everytime you save a resource and split up the content, create/delete sibling resources as needed etc. Sounds like a lot of work for what you want to archieve to me.

I suppose you have a look at the [MIGX](http://modx.com/extras/package/migx) extra. It provides you with a TV with the possibility to store an indefinite amount of distinct TV content sets. Have a look at the [documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/addon/MIGX) and Mark Hamstra's [tutorial](http://www.markhamstra.com/modx-blog/2012/04/managing-galleries-with-migx/) (with screenshots) to see how it is done. You should define one MIGX entry to consist of a text field for the `<h1>` and a rich text field for the content of the "subpage".

Afterwards, you can use [form customization](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Form+Customization+Sets) to hide the original content field and display your MIGX Tv instead.

I think, this is a much easier way to archieve, what you want, and can't think of any way, where you would benefit from actual subpages.

Edit: Sorry, I just recognized that you were asking about Evolution, not Revolution. My solution would work in Revo, but I don't think there's something like MIGX for Evo. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Yes, the plugin sounds like it, newer tried to do one though. Your MIGX idea might work in Evo with this: http://www.kunane.com/modx/multi-image-tv.html ..but like there were in question; subpages needs to be actual subpages. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But why exactly do they need to be subpages? What do you want to do with the subpages? I'm pretty sure, you might do this some other way with the content in a multi-image tv and it would be easier to archieve...?

Answer (score 0):

not 'out of the box' you will have to run your content through a snippet to parse it into separate divs or something that you can run some javascript on to possibly 'tab' the content.
If you need to show the 'subpages' in your navigation, you will probably have to use the gatResources extra to parse your content ~ which will be very expensive on resource usage.

Comment: I need to do this in MODX; sub-pages got to be actual subpages, and original page becomes to container. I need to add this info to my question :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can (depending on how you're using the tree) just create actual sub resources under the parent resource, using Ditto or Wayfinder to build navigation for it.

If you can't use the tree like that (though from your description I think you can), you could also set up a number of template variables ("content1", "content2", "content3" etc) and show that with a simple snippet or so.

Comment: Yep. That is what i am doing right now :) I was - and still am - wondering if there was something i could use or code to handle this instead of manually loop create, cut, paste.

Comment: If your subpages together build the container page, you can just use Ditto to aggregate the subcontainers into one page, no? Using wayfinder (or Ditto again if you want to) to build the links to individual pages. (Sorry for late response, only noticed the notification now, teehee)